# replace NA is selected columns with replace_na

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains columns `hh_c22j, hh_r02a, hh_r02b`. I want to replace `NA`s in these col with 0. Right now I have the command as below, it works. But is redundant, as I need to specify for each column to replace with 0.

```
df %>% select(case_id, hh_c22j, hh_r02a, hh_r02b) %>% replace_na(list(hh_c22j=0, hh_r02a=0, hh_r02b=0))
```

I want to select the columns together in an array/list like below.

```
df %>% select(case_id, hh_c22j, hh_r02a, hh_r02b) %>% replace_na(c(hh_c22j, hh_r02a, hh_r02b), 0)
```

But I got an error. The error msg is :

```
Error in is_list(replace) : object 'hh_c22j' not found
Error: 1 components of `...` were not used.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `..1`

Did you misspecify an argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlib_error_dots_unused>
1 components of `...` were not used.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `..1`

Did you misspecify an argument?
Backtrace:
 1. `%>%`(...)
 5. ellipsis:::action_dots(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have other columns in the data as well but want to change just the three columns, you can do this:

```
library(dplyr) 

df %>% mutate_at(vars(hh_c22j, hh_r02a, hh_r02b), list(~ replace(., which(is.na(.)), 0)))

# Alternatively, using replace_na
df %>% mutate_at(vars(hh_c22j, hh_r02a, hh_r02b), list(~ replace_na(., 0)))
```

Just for future reference, a small reproducible sample would go a long way to get better answers!

Comment: could you explain why you use the `list` function and include the tilde in front of `replace`? I ran your code without `list(~ ...)` and it doesn't work. Why `replace` alone doesn't work here? Thanks!

Comment: I am not at all an expert on this (caveat), but `list(~ ...)` call replaces the now deprecated `funs()` call that specifies anonymous functions within `mutate`. See: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/funs.html#:~:text=funs()%20is%20deprecated%3B%20please,other%20packages%20in%20the%20tidyverse.

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this in a clean way is make use of the `mutate_all` function and pass it the function to use on each of the columns. For example, here I create a dataset similar to what you have and replace the null values with 0s:

```
data <- data.frame(hh_c22j = sample(c(NA, 1), size = 5, replace = TRUE),
                   hh_r02a = sample(c(NA, 1), size = 5, replace = TRUE),
                   hh_r02b = sample(c(NA, 1), size = 5, replace = TRUE)) 

data %>% 
  mutate_all(replace_na, 0)
```

If you only want to perform this operation on some columns, `mutate_at` is a similar option where you can specify which column(s) to use this on.

Comment: thanks! I appreciate the reproducible data frame sample. I didn't know how to do that.